# Unable to set visible property of pivotitem

Tags: excel, vba

I have a pivottable based on data.

I am iterating over the pivotitems twice:
First iteration: set all to visible
Second iterationg: set all but desired to `Visible=False`

Now - I am getting an error that my code is trying to set all elements (Visible=False).

When i look at the pivot manually i do not see my element in the sub-filter list, but when I search for the item  (using the pivottable magnifying glass/search) i find the item in the list.

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: Difficult to suggest anything without your code.

Answer (score 0):

I was checking for exact case match. Apparently there is not case sensitivity among pivot items.